# How do I suppress CosmosDB "default" info in resultsets?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want to suppress the CosmosDB information in the following resultset, how can that be done?

```
 {
            "id": null,
            "_rid": null,
            "_self": null,
            "_ts": 0,
            "_etag": null,
            "topLevelCategory": "Shorts,Skirt"
 },
```

This is an extract of course but I dont want to show the ID etc as they serve no purpose in this result but I cannot figure out how to suppress that info.

I expect the following

```
 {
            "topLevelCategory": "Shorts,Skirt"
 },
```

Query looks as follows

```
 $"SELECT DISTINCT locales.categories[0] AS topLevelCategory " +
                                                 $"FROM c JOIN locales in c.locales " +
                                                 $"WHERE locales.country = '{apiInputObject.Locale}' " +
                                                 $"AND locales.language = '{apiInputObject.Language}'";
```

Interesting thing is if I cast the  result as a JOBJECT I dont get the system data, I only get it if I createDOcumentQuery as DOcument, so a workaround would be as follows

```
IQueryable<JObject> queryResultSet = client.CreateDocumentQuery<JObject>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, databaseCollection), parsedQueryObject.SqlStatement, queryOptions);
```

but that has other async issues but the above does not show the system generate IDs but the below one does

```
 var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, databaseCollection), parsedQueryObject.SqlStatement, queryOptions).AsDocumentQuery();
                        var result = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<Document>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [system-generated properties of items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/databases-containers-items#properties-of-an-item) in Cosmos DB.

[image]

Surely,you could filter them in the sql: `select c.topLevelCategory from c`, don't mention them or use `select * from c`. Filtering  in sql is the best method, better than secondary processing of result set.

---

***Update Answer:***

Your situation is executing the exact same query the JOBJECT does not show the system data but the Document does.

My explanation as below:

[Document Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.document?view=azure-dotnet) is a self-contained base class of Document DB .NET package.It has these generate properties:

[image]

SDK will try to map the result data one by one to the entity class which you defined in the `CreateDocumentQuery<T>`.

So actually,you already find the solution.You could define your custom pojo to receive the result data. Just contain the properties you want in that pojo inside like:

```
class Pojo : Document
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

That would have both business implications and no more redundant fields.Hope i'm clear on this.

Comment: I am not mentioning them and I am not using select * but they still appear and I also wish there is a way to not have it as they increase the data I am sending down to the mobile devices about 6 times.

Comment: @MattDouhan Hi,would you please tell me how you query the data?

Comment: I Edited and added the query

Comment: I just tested and execute the exact same query the JOBJECT does not show the system data but the Document does